# having trouble understanding an array of objects embedded within a data class structure

Tags: java

I am trying to create a nested data structure that is static.
One of the nested items is an object array.
I cannot seem to assign new objects to that array.
This is most likely trivial to the gurus at large out there in the ether.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class test
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
{

 //===========================================
 public static class DataClass
 //===========================================
  { 
    static String thing = new String("thing 1");
  
    public static class InnerClass
    { 
      static String thing = new String("thing 2");
      
      public class this_thingy
      {
        String thing;
        String other;
        void init() { thing="thing 3"; other="other"; }
      } 
      public static this_thingy[] classArray = new this_thingy[3];
      
    }

  }//DataClass

 //===========================================
  public static void main( String[] args )
 //===========================================
  {
    System.out.println( DataClass.InnerClass.thing );
    
    System.out.println( DataClass.InnerClass.classArray[0].thing );
    System.out.println( DataClass.InnerClass.classArray[0].other );
  }//main

}//test


/*
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because "test$DataClass$InnerClass_3.InnerClass_3a" is null
        at test.main(test.java:31)
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize each element of the array.

```
public static class this_thingy{
    String thing;
    String other;
    void init() { thing="thing 3"; other="other"; }
} 
public static this_thingy[] classArray = new this_thingy[3];
static {
   for(int i = 0; i < classArray.length; i++){
      (classArray[i] = new this_thingy()).init();
   }
}
```

Comment: Close.  Here is what I see now:

test.java:27: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
            classArray[i] = new this_thingy();
                            ^

Comment: @Rod What does it give you?

Comment: THANKS iota !!   My last problem was that I needed to delete the *.class files. After that, smooth sailing.   Thank you Very Much for the solution !

Comment: @Rod No problem.